# What steps to take when doing V&V for a computer simulation?

Tags: validation, matlab, statistics, simulation, verification

I have a simulation that emulates an electric fish inside of a tank. I have some experimental data to map the results against, but hope to do most computations on my model. In order to faithfully use the model, I need to verify and validate (V&V) my model.

The way I understand it, the two tasks can be simply described as this:

- "Am I building the right system?" (Validation)
- "Am I building the system right?" (Verification) (pg75, 1)

I feel like I have validated my system, but now must verify it.

As a relatively new programmer, I am wondering what steps must be taken, what steps can be skipped, and what steps would be a good bonus in order to effectively (and relatively efficiently) verify my system. This system is for an educational institution, and has applications in health care research, so I feel that I should not move too quickly past the verification stage.

*My concern within the verification stage is not how to test my model, or to gather those results. My question is this, what methods should I use to compare my data, as in which types of statistics will be most useful, for showing an accurate, and consistent proof of my data quality.*

Many Thanks.

P.s. If this is a repeat post, please point me in the direction of an answered question as I've probably searched with the wrong keywords.

---

**Resources:**

(1):   Verification and Validation in Systems Engineering. *Debbabi, M. et. al*. 1st Edition. 2010. XXVI.

**Edit:**
The italicized paragraph added.

Comment: Another one for your reading list: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Verification-Validation-Scientific-Computing-Oberkampf/dp/0521113601/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1340723453&sr=1-1  My own view is that this is far too big a topic to fit neatly into the SO Q&A format, but I'll watch this one with interest.

Comment: @High Performance Mark -- Thanks for your comment!

Comment: This is a fairly open ended question.  Generally verification gets at the correctness of your algorithms and code that they accurately represent the physics and other phenomenon that you are trying to simulate.  Depending on how stringent your customer is regarding V&V, you may want to get a third party to do this step for you (assuming that you prepare the documentation supporting your modeling approach).

Comment: Okay, I sense that I worded my problem somewhat incorrectly, allow me to edit it to clarify which part I need the most assistance with. Thanks for your comment!